# Is there a way to instantiate a child class with parent object in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, instantiation

I have a base class say

```
class A {
   private String name;
   private String age;

   //setters and getters for same
}
```

and a child class say

```
class B extends A {
 private String phone;
 private String address;

  //setters and getters for same
}
```

now I've an instance of A and besides this I have to set the fields in B as well, so code would be like,

```
A instanceOfA = gotAFromSomewhere();
B instanceOfB = constructBFrom(instanceOfA);
instanceOfB.setPhone(getPhoneFromSomewhere());
instanceOfB.setAddress(getAddressFromSomewhere());
```

can I instantiate B with given A, but **I don't want to do this way**,

```
B constructBFrom(A instanceOfA) {
  final B instanceOfB = new B();
  instanceOfB.setName(instanceOfA.getName());
  instanceOfB.setPhone(instanceOfA.getAge());

  return B;
}
```

rather what I'd love to have some utility with function which is generic enough to construct object as in,

```
public class SomeUtility {

   public static <T1, T2> T2 constructFrom(T1 instanceOfT1, Class<T2> className) {

      T2 instatnceOfT2 = null;

      try {
         instatnceOfT2 = className.newInstance();
         /*
         * Identifies the fields in instanceOfT1 which has same name in T2
         * and sets only these fields and leaves the other fields as it is.
         */
      } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
         // handle exception
      }          

      return instatnceOfT2;
   }
}
```

so that I can use it as,

```
B constructBFrom(A instanceOfA) {
   return SomeUtility.constructFrom(instanceOfA, B.class);
}
```

Moreover, use case will not be only limited to parent-child classes, rather this utility function can be used for adapter use cases.

**PS- A and B are third party classes I've to use these classes only so I can't do any modifications
in A and B.**

Comment: Declare a `B` constructor that accepts an `A`.

Comment: What do you expect the resulting `B` to look like? Simply a copy of the instance of `A` with the fields of `B` set to null?

Comment: sounds like an _XY problem_ to me...   What's the _real_ problem you're trying to solve?   I can't imagine any decent use case for trying to do this.

Comment: @Alnitak - a decent use case may be e.g. creating a specific `XXXList` based on the generic `List`. Although you are probably right - I am also quite suspicious about the OP's motivation :)

Comment: There's no way to set the name and age of a `B` anyway without explicitly calling `setName` and `setAge`, since as written `B` doesn't have a constructor that takes name and age as parameters. By the way, `instanceOfA.getPhone()` is a compile error, since `A` doesn't have `phone` or `getPhone`.

Comment: If A and B are 3rd party classes, and there is no obvious way to convert between the two, this is almost certainly by design, and unless you have an intimate familiarity with the library, you should be careful manipulating the object structure.

Comment: @shelly - see edit to my answer below. Tell us WHAT you want your hack FOR. It looks dirty from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 12):

The good practice is to have a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) class which "produces" the instances of `B`.

```
public class BFactory {
    public B createBFromA(A a) { ... }
}
```

You *have to* write the code of the factory method as there is no standard way of creating a child class based on its parent class. It's always specific and depends on the logic of your classes.

However, consider if it is *really* what you need. There are *not many* smart use cases for instantiating a class based on the instance of its parent. One good example is [ArrayList(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) - constructs a *specific* list ("child") containing the elements of the *generic* collection ("base").

Actually, for many situation there *is* a pattern to avoid such strange constructs. I am aware it's probably not applicable to your specific case as you wrote that your Base and Child are 3rd party classes. However your question title was generic enough so I think you may find the following useful.

1. Create an interface `IBase`
2. Let the class `Base` implement the interface
3. Use [composition instead of inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - let `Child` **use** `Base` instead of inheriting it
4. Let `Child` implement `IBase` and delegate all the methods from `IBase` to the instance of `Base`

Your code will look like this:

```
public interface IBase {
    String getName();
    int getAge();
}

public class Base implements IBase {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // getters implementing IBase
}

public class Child implements IBase {
    // composition:
    final private IBase base;        
    public Child(IBase base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    // delegation:
    public String getName() {
        return base.getName();
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return base.getAge();
    }
}
```

After you edited your question, I doubt even stronger that what you want is good. Your question looks more like an attempt of a hack, of violating (or not understanding) the principles of [class-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) object oriented concept. Sounds to me like someone coming from the JavaScript word and trying to keep the JavaScript programming style and just use a different syntax of Java, instead of adopting a different language philosophy.

Fun-fact: Instantiating a child object with parent object is possible in [prototype-based languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), see the example in JavaScript 1.8.5:

```
var base = {one: 1, two: 2};
var child = Object.create(base);
child.three = 3;

child.one;   // 1
child.two;   // 2
child.three; // 3
```

Comment: that's assuming that the OP's required construct is even a good idea in the first place...

Comment: @Alnitak - you are absolutely right. I have added a note.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the way you want to avoid is very appropriate. There must be a piece of such code somewhere.

If you can't put that method in the target class just put it somewhere else (some factory). You should additionaly make your method `static`.

Take a look at [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

**2nd option** would be extending B and place this method as factory static method in that new class. But this solution seems to be more complicated for me. Then you could call `NewB.fromA(A)`. You should be able then use your NewB instead of B then.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via reflection:

```
public static void copyFields(Object source, Object target) {
        Field[] fieldsSource = source.getClass().getFields();
        Field[] fieldsTarget = target.getClass().getFields();

        for (Field fieldTarget : fieldsTarget)
        {
            for (Field fieldSource : fieldsSource)
            {
                if (fieldTarget.getName().equals(fieldSource.getName()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fieldTarget.set(target, fieldSource.get(source));
                    }
                    catch (SecurityException e)
                    {
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {
                    }
                    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                    {
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*Above code copied from online tutorial